# jQuery show each sibling's text loop of XML

Tags: jquery, html, xml

I have some jQuery statements, the 1st works but the 2nd doesn't.

```
$('<h2>', { text: $person.find('name').text() }).appendTo($div);
$('<h3>', { text: $person.find('rooms').each('room').text() }).appendTo($div);
```

What I am trying to do with the 2nd statement is print out each sibling named room of each 'rooms' parent node. The XML data looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<people>
    <person>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Annex</name>
        <rooms>
            <room>100</room>
            <room>203</room>
        </rooms>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Library</name>
        <rooms>
            <room>101</room>
            <room>102</room>
        </rooms>
    </person>
</people>
```

I understand how the 1st statement works, it prints out the name of each building. But how can I fix the 2nd statement to print each room of rooms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the room set and then create the `h3` & append it to the div like

```
$person.find('rooms room').each(function () {
    $('<h3>', {
        text: $(this).text()
    }).appendTo($div);
})
```

- [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) does not take a string as an argument
- since you need to create multiple `h3` elements, you need to use an iterator

Comment: Thanks, I am new to jquery and short-hand coding... So what is the iterator in your answer since there is no index variable?

Comment: @Jim22150 the each method act like an iterator... `.find('rooms room')` returns a set of matching elements(2 in your case) and the `.each(function(){})` will call the passed function for each element in the set